# Expert Suggestions about State Machine Design

Tags: node.js, state-machine

**Background**

We were designing a micro-service to manage bookings in our system. So we decided to solve this using state-machine abstraction, i.e Bookings can be in one of multiple states, and can be transitioned to another through some actions/events.

We had a very healthy discussions between me and my colleague and I had some different opinion about how the state machine should be designed.
I took an example of [REDUX](https://redux.js.org/), where we have different **ACTIONS** (EVENTS + PAYLOAD) and based on **ACTION.TYPE** we transition our system to another **STATE**.

This was fairly simple but my friend introduced confusing factor like **ACTIONS** and **EVENTS**:  two complete different things (which in my opinion should be same in any state-machine)
And he is arguing that **EVENTS** cause some **ACTIONS** to perform on a state-machine to transition to some another **STATE**. And his point is **EVENTS** & **ACTIONS** are two complete different aspects and should not be same. They have different points and implications.

For e.g Certain **EVENT** may be **CREATE_REQUEST** , but actually looking for availability and making a booking is a **ACTION** derived by **CREATE_REQUEST** event.

But I completely disagree and I am strongly saying an **ACTION** should be something like **[CREATE_REQUEST, {DATES, ...OTHER_INFO}]** and the machine should perform accordingly and transitioned to some other **STATE** .

so what should be the correct approach.

```js
├── src
|  ├── ACTIONS
|  ├────── CREATE_REQUEST // return {TYPE: CREATE_REQUEST, {data}}
|  ├────── DECLINE_REQUEST //return {TYPE: DECLINE_REQUEST, {id}}
|  ├── STATES
|  ├────── DRAFT
|  ├────── PENDING
|  ├────── REQUESTED
|  ├────── COMPLETE
```

I am waiting for some expert suggestions and advice so that we can have a clear vision on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The action represents what the user interacts with. The event is how your application deals with said interactions. It is wise to implement an arbitration layer in most cases, depending on the size of the project. Once you are convinced of the importance of the architecture of the application you should implement events handling the user actions. You simply don't want to put all your business logic into the actions. Doing so is a surefire way to making the code unmaintainable.